# My fig1.savefig function is saving my figure as a blank screen, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am importing data by a .csv file and am plotting it, but when I plot my figure and try to save it to my google drive it only saves a blank image with none of the data. I am using Google Collaboratory.

Here is my code:

```
#Displaying the Data


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.title("Score of Each Raisan Thrown", fontsize ='x-large')

plt.ylabel("Valid Raisans Thrown", fontsize='large')
plt.xlabel("Score", fontsize= 'large')

dart = data[:,0]
score =  data[:,1]

plt.plot(score ,dart, marker='o', linestyle='none', color='black')

ax = plt.subplot()

ax.set_facecolor('seashell')

# Adding ticks to make my plot easier to understand/read

ax.set_yticks([20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200])
ax.set_xticks([-16,-14,-12,-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,-16])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.draw()
fig.savefig(datapath+'My Experiment1 Plot')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.draw()
fig.savefig(datapath+'My Experiment1 Plot')
```

comes after all the drawing commands, which means you are creating a **new figure** without plotting anything and just save it. You need to rearrange your commands:

```
# get the data:
dart = data[:,0]
score =  data[:,1]

# set up the fig and axes:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

# plot the data
plt.plot(score ,dart, marker='o', linestyle='none', color='black')

# additional formatting
plt.title("Score of Each Raisan Thrown", fontsize ='x-large')
plt.ylabel("Valid Raisans Thrown", fontsize='large')
plt.xlabel("Score", fontsize= 'large')

# even more formatting
ax.set_facecolor('seashell')

# Adding ticks to make my plot easier to understand/read    
ax.set_yticks([20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200])
ax.set_xticks([-16,-14,-12,-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,-16])

fig.savefig(datapath+'My Experiment1 Plot')

plt.show()
```